# How to display numeric value in the MessageBox() ?in c++

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to display the screen resolution pixels as output in MessageBox. How can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a float number to visual c++ messagebox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826097/how-to-print-a-float-number-to-visual-c-messagebox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CString msg;
msg.Format(_T("%d"), number);
AfxMessageBox(msg);
```